# How to find the intersections between a sine and cosine function when both have translations and dilations applied

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I'm asking for how to solve the general equation $ A \sin(x+B)+C=D \cos(x+E)+F$ essentially

No matter which approach I take, I find that I cannot isolate the terms within the two functions to find x

thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. It would be useful to write the problem as an equation. Are you interested in  solutions of $A \sin(x + B) = C \cos(x + D)$?

Comment: Ty for you tip I'll edit my original post!

Comment: I don't know that the general equation can be solved even in simple cases like $\sin (x) = \cos (x)$. You may have to settle for a numerical approximation.

Comment: I'm not feeling confident about my case but sin(x) = cos(x) can be solved pretty simply
I had the working but it doesn't really work as a comment but basically you just square both sides, sub out one of the terms with the pythagorean identity and continue onwards

Comment: $A \sin(x+B)-D\cos(x+E)=F-C$, $(A \cos B + D \sin E) \sin x + (A\sin B - D \cos E)\cos x = F-C$. $a \sin x + b \cos x = c$, $\cos \phi =\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, $\sin \phi = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, $\sin(x+\phi)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Comment: To begin, you can reduce the number of constants by dividing by $A$ or $D$ and by solving for the unknown $y = x + B$, such that $x + E = y + E-B$.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sin(x+\phi_i)$ always can be transformed to $a \sin(x+\phi)$. This transform can be done using Moivre formula or some other methods like in my previous comment.